# Null property provided by Gradle when using custom plugin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to follow the [Gradle custom plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.9.1/userguide/custom_plugins.html) to create a plugin that can be configured.

My plugin code:

```
interface MyExtension {
    var myValue: Property<String>
}

class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        val extension = project.extensions.create<MyExtension>("myExt")
    }
}
```

in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    `java-library`
}

apply<MyPlugin>()
the<MyExtension>().myValue.set("some-value")
```

Running this will give

```
Build file '<snip>/build.gradle.kts' line: 6
java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

Turns out the `the<MyExtension>().myValue` is `null`, so the `set` call fails. How do I do this correctly? Did I miss something in the documentation, or is it just wrong?

Comment: Tool versions: Gradle 6.9.1, openjdk 11, Kotlin 1.4.20

Comment: I'm not into Kotlin, but the documentation uses `open class MyExtension`, whereas you're using `interface MyExtension`. Also, `myValue` needs to be initialized otherwise you cannot execute `set()` on it, right? At least the documentation says so.

Comment: I tried an `abstract class` too, same result. And there's nothing in the docs about initializing the `Property`, that's Gradle's job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is not wrong. Properties can be managed by either you or by Gradle. For the latter, certain conditions have to be met.

#### Without managed properties

If you want to be completely in charge, you can instantiate any variables you declare yourself. For example, to declare a property on an extension that is an interface, it could look like this:

```kotlin
override fun apply(project: Project) {
  val extension = project.extensions.create("myExt", MyExtension::class.java)
  extension.myValue = project.objects.property(String::class.java)
}
```

Or you could instantiate it directly in the extension by making it a class instead:

```kotlin
open class MessageExtension(objects: ObjectFactory) {
  val myValue: Property<String> = objects.property(String::class.java)
}
```

However, a property field is not really supposed to have a setter as the property itself has both a setter and a getter. So you should generally avoid the first approach and remove the setter on the second.

See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/6.9.1/userguide/lazy_configuration.html) for more examples on managing the properties yourself.

#### With managed properties

To help you reduce boilerplate code, Gradle can instantiate the properties for you with what is called *managed properties*. To do use these, the property must *not* have a setter, and the getter should be abstract (which it implicitly is on an interface). So you could go back to your first example and fix it by changing `var` to `val`:

```kotlin
interface MyExtension {
    val myValue: Property<String> // val (getter only)
}
```

Now Gradle will instantiate the field for you. The same thing works for abstract classes.

Read more about managed properties in the documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_gradle_types.html#configuration_using_properties).

Comment: Perfect! So it's the difference between `val` and `var`. Could certainly use a mention in the user guide/tutorial, but your answer explains it very well.